# Does uniform continuity of the differential imply uniform differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, uniform-continuity

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset. $f:E \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, and suppose that $\nabla f$ is uniformly continuous.

> Is it true that $f$ is "uniformly differentiable"? i.e. does there exist, for any $\epsilon >0$, a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $a,x \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
>   $$\frac{|f(x) - f(a) - \nabla f (a)\cdot (x-a)|}{|x-a|} <\epsilon$$
>   whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.

**I can prove this for any convex $E$. (see below). Is it true for non-convex domains as well?**

*My proof:*

$\nabla f$ uniformly continuous implies that for any $\epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)|<\epsilon.$$

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be fixed. Choose $x,a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|x-a| < \delta$. By the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables) (for convex domains), there is a $z$ on the line segment connecting $a$ and $x$ such that

$$f(x) - f(a) = \nabla f (z) \cdot (x-a).$$

Then

$$\begin{align}
\frac{|f(x) - f(a) - \nabla f (a)\cdot (x-a)|}{|x-a|} &=  
  \frac{|(\nabla f(z) - \nabla f(a)) \cdot (x-a)|}{|x-a|} \\
& \leq  \frac{|\nabla f(z) - \nabla f(a)| |x-a|}{|x-a|} \\
& <  \epsilon
\end{align},$$

since $|z-a| < |x-a| < \delta$.

Comment: The only requirement you need is that $E$ be open and **connected.** Any open connected subset of the Euclidean space is path and polygonally connected.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Does that mean it's not possible to prove this when $E$ is not connected?

Comment: I don't think it's true when your open set $E$ is not connected. Remove the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:\frac{-1}{1+x^{2}}\le y\le\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}\}$ from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and refer to it as $E$. This results in two disconnected open sets. Define a function $g$ as $1$ on one component and $-1$ on the other. $g$ is differentiable on $E$ and the derivative is uniformly continuous. However, $g$ is not uniformly differentiable.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's not true if $E$ is not connected. Though I'm a bit puzzled how the proof will change if the open set $E$ is connected only, and not convex.

Comment: The reciprocal is true? if $E$ is open and not connected.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the claim does not hold for general non-convex domains.

If you take $f$ to be the standard angle function on $E=\mathbb R^2\setminus([0,\infty)×\{0\})$, then $f:E \to (0,2\pi)$ is a counterexample.

Indeed, taking $x,a$ very close on the unit circle $\mathbb S^1$, with angles approaching zero (from above) and $2\pi$ from  below, we get $f(x) - f(a) \to 2\pi$ with $x-a \to 0$. Thus, the fraction
$$
\frac{|f(x) - f(a) - \nabla f (a)\cdot (x-a)|}{|x-a|}
$$

explodes.