# If $f$ is uniformly differentiable then $f '$ is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

The following theorem is true?

**Theorem.** Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ (open set) and $f:U\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a differentiable function.

If $f$  is uniformly differentiable  $ \Longrightarrow$ $f':U\longrightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is uniformly continuous.

Note that  $f$ is uniformly differentiable if

$\forall \epsilon>0\,,\exists \delta>0:|\!|h|\!|<\delta,\color{blue}{[x,x+h]\subset U} \Longrightarrow |\!|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)(h)|\!|<\epsilon |\!|h|\!| $ (edited)

$\forall \epsilon>0\,,\exists \delta>0:|\!|h|\!|<\delta,\color{blue}{x,x+h\in U} \Longrightarrow |\!|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)(h)|\!|<\epsilon |\!|h|\!|\qquad  \checkmark$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition for uniformly differentiable?

Comment: @Tomás $\forall \epsilon>0\,,\exists \delta>0:|\!|h|\!|<\delta,[x,x+h]\subset U \Longrightarrow |\!|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)(h)|\!|<\epsilon |\!|h|\!|$

Comment: What did you try ? (I think you know the proof in the case $\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$).

Comment: Do you know the proof in this case @TonyPiccolo?

Comment: See my **new attempt**.

Comment: [@TonyPiccolo] How you proof that $\|(f'(x+h)-f'(x))(k)\|<3\varepsilon \|k\|$ ?

Comment: I edit supposing $\|k\|=\|h\|\,$ instead.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Note that $x+k$ not necessarily belong to $U$, $x$ can be well glued to the border of $U$, if fixed $||h||$  then also fixed $||k||$ .

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I think $U$ is an connected open, we need a counterexample.

Comment: Let $U$ be simply open: then $f'$ is u.c. on $\{x\in U:\ {\rm dist}\,(x,\Bbb R^m\backslash U)>\Delta\}$ with $\Delta>0$ chosen sufficiently small. I edit with $\delta$ chosen in $(0,\Delta)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's build off of Tomas' last remark, slightly modified:

Let $t>0$ be small. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
 \|f'(x)-f'(y)\| &=& \frac{1}{t}\sup_{\|w\|=1}\|\langle f'(x)-f'(y),tw\rangle\|      \nonumber \\
   &\leq& \frac{1}{t}\sup_{\|w\|=1}\|f(x+tw)-f(x)-[f(y+tw)-f(y)]\| + 2\epsilon \nonumber 
\end{eqnarray}

It suffices to show that this weighted combination of four close points on a parallelogram can be bounded by $C\epsilon t$.

Let us bound $\|f(x+h) - f(x) + f(x+k) - f(x+h+k)\|_2 \leq C\epsilon(\|h\|+\|k\|)$, and then in this case $\|h\|=t$ and $\|k\|\leq \delta$, so if $t=\delta$ the whole expression is bounded by a constant times $\epsilon$.

Note applying uniform differentiability three times in directions $h,k,$ and $h+k$, for small $\|h\|,\|k\|$ we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\|f(x+h) - f(x) + f(x+k) - f(x+h+k)\| &\leq& \|f'(x)h + f'(x)k - f'(x)(h+k)\|_2 + 3\epsilon(\|h\|+\|k\|)\\
 &=& 3\epsilon(\|h\|+\|k\|)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Shouldn't the first occurrence of $2 \epsilon$ actually be $2\epsilon/t$? I'm not sure you can magick away the magnitude of $w$ like that.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  The original equation had $\epsilon |w|$, but since I replaced $w$ with $tw$, that's where the extra $t$ comes from.

Comment: oh right. It works.

Comment: @Evan only a question, the following equivalence is true ? $\forall \epsilon>0\,,\exists \delta>0:|\!|h|\!|<\delta,\color{blue}{[x,x+h]\subset U} \Longrightarrow |\!|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)(h)|\!\!|<\epsilon |\!|h|\!|\Longleftrightarrow \forall \epsilon>0\,,\exists \delta>0:|\!|h|\!|<\delta,\color{blue}{x,x+h \in U} \Longrightarrow |\!|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)(h)|\!\!|<\epsilon |\!|h|\!|$

Comment: @felipeuni  Yes that is true, because the property only depends on $x$ and $x+h$, so there's no distinction here.

Comment: Isn't the first property strictly weaker in general since it is quantified over a smaller collection of $x,h$?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis so the distinction is one of pathconnectedness? I suppose you are right

Comment: @Evan: convexity seems more relevant. If we modify the statements to let $\delta$ depend on $x$ then they are equivalent since $U$ is open; but as is I think we need $U$ to be convex.

Comment: Take for example $U=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ and $f(x \in (0,1)) = x^2, f(x \in (1,2)) = (x-1)^2$. Then $f$ is uniformly differentiable in felipeuni's sense but $f'$ is non-uniformly continuous.

Comment: ah okay, but then that makes the problem a bit silly I suppose

Comment: @Evan Note that $t=||h||+||k||$, $x+tw \in U$ ?

Comment: @felipeuni  for sufficiently small $t$.so the idea here for this t factor was that we could work with four close points in the estimate

Comment: @Evan Note that if you make $t=||h||+||k||$ then will form a cyclic dependency $\delta\neq\delta(\epsilon)$(uniform continuity).Would be interesting to see a proof with arguments $\epsilon-\delta$.

Comment: @Evan But your proof is correct if $U=\mathbb{R}^m$ making $t=||h||+||k||$.

Comment: @felipeuni  sorry, that $t$ choice is very confusing, I edited now, perhaps it is more clear (suffices to take $t$ to the same level as $\delta$)

Comment: How do we guarantee $x + tw$ and $y + tw$ are both in $U$? If not, we don't even know if $f(x+tw)$ and $f(y+tw)$ are defined. It seems to me your proof doesn't work for $x$ close to the boundary of $U$.

Answer (score 5):

This answer only the case $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$. By hypothesis we have that: given $\epsilon>0$, there exist $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$ $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-f'(y)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\tag{1}$$

and

$$\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}-f'(x)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\tag{2}$$

From $(2)$ we get that $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-f'(x)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\tag{3}$$

From $(1)$ and $(3)$ $$|f'(x)-f'(y)|<\epsilon$$

I dont know how to tackle the case $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m$.

Update: I would like to add here some thoughts, maybe it can help someone to give a full answer. First note that

\begin{eqnarray}
 \|f'(x)-f'(y)\| &=& \sup_{\|w\|=1}\|\langle f'(x)-f'(y),w\rangle\|      \nonumber \\
   &=& \sup_{\|w\|=1}\|f(x+w)-f(x)-[f(y+w)-f(y)]+o(x,w)-o(y,w)\| \nonumber 
\end{eqnarray}

By hypothesis, $\|o(x,w)-o(y,w)\|\leq \epsilon\|w\|+\epsilon\|w\|$, hence for $\|w\|=1$ we have that $\sup_{\|w\|=1}\|o(x,w)-o(y,w)\|$ is small, independetly of $x,y$. Therefore, it remains to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous. One way to prove it is for example showing that $f'$ is bounded, which I think is true when $U$ is bounded. When $U$ is unbounded, I think we need a direct argument to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: [Tomás] Note that $[x,y]\subset \mathbb{U}$ then $U$ should be an interval, definition of uniformly differentiable.

Comment: @felipeuni you need to specify where are $x,y$. If $x,y$ are any points on $U$, then the only thing you can conclude is that $U$ is convex.

Comment: For bounded regions, take the closure to get a compact set, and then it's clear that $f$ is uniformly continuous. For unbounded regions, as you say we need a direct argument, as $f$ is not uniformly continuous in general, with a 1-d counterexample $f(x) = x^2$...

Comment: How do you go from stap (3) to the next?

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty here is that the obvious estimate (as in Tomás' answer) only gives a result along lines - i.e. it can't say anything about how $f'(x)h$ changes as you move in any direction but $h$. Thus I think we need some kind of "polarization argument" to get an isotropic result. When $f$ is $C^2$, this is literally polarizing the Hessian matrix $H(x) = f''(x)$ to show it is bounded from the fact that it is bounded on the diagonal. While we cannot use this literally for general $f$, hopefully we can use a finite-difference analogy and the analysis will go through. Here's the proof for the $C^2$ case and an optimistic starting point for the general case.

For any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,h$ with $|h|<\delta$, we have (cf. Tomás' answer)

$$
\begin{align}
|f(x+h) - f(x) - f'(x)h| &< \epsilon |h| \\
|f(x) - f(x+h) + f'(x+h)h| &< \epsilon |h| 
\end{align}
$$

which combine to give $$t|(f'(x+t v)-f'(x))v| < 2 \epsilon $$ for $v$ a unit vector, $t<\delta$.

In the $C^2$ case the left side is $t^2 |H(x)(v,v)| + o(t^2)$, so we have a uniform bound $$|H(x)(v,v)| < M \tag{1}.$$ The polarization formula is $$ H(x)(v,w) = \frac12 \left( H(x)(v+w,v+w) - H(x)(v,v) - H(x)(w,w) \right). \tag{2}$$

We want to show uniform continuity of $f'$. A line integral estimate gives $$ |f'(x)w-f'(y)w| \le |x-y| \sup_{z \in U} |H(z)\left(v,w\right)|$$ where $|x-y|v = x-y$; so it suffices to show that $\sup_{z \in U, |v| = 1} H(z)(v,w)$ is finite. Applying $(1)$ and $(2)$ we estimate

$$ 
\begin{align}
|H(z)(v,w)| & \le \frac12 M \left( |v+w|^2 + |v|^2 + |w|^2 \right)\\
& \le M \left( 1 + |w| + |w|^2 \right)
\end{align}
$$

so we are done.

Now to try generalising this. Attempting to write down the polarization formula using finite difference terms gives

$$
\begin{align}
&(f'(x+v+w) - f'(x+v))w + (f'(x+w+v)-f'(x+w))v \\
= &(f'(x+v+w) - f'(x))(v+w) - (f'(x+v)-f'(x))v-(f'(x+w) - f'(x))w \\
\end{align}$$

which (since $f$ is uniformly differentiable) is bounded by $2 \epsilon (|v+w| + |v| + |w|)$.

Now we would like to equate the two terms on the LHS, which is the reason polarization works for symmetric forms. Our expression is of course *not* symmetric but we can hope it is close enough for small $u,v$ - I have no idea whether or not this can be done without more assumptions, however. If anyone has any ideas (or has spotted any mistakes) please let me know.

Comment: Maybe we could approximate $f$ by $C^2$ functions?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis@Tomás I think the following article Theorem $3.4$ could help. http://www.physics.umanitoba.ca/~khodr/Publications/RSImplicitFT-Final.pdf

Comment: @felipeuni: that theorem is for non-Archimedian fields, however at first glance the proof seems to work for the Euclidean case too! In fact it may even directly prove what you're looking for - I haven't been through it in detail but the estimates are probably all uniform in $x_0$. I think it's very similar to Evan's answer, which seems to be a complete proof.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis the link is broken. The name of the article is "The implicit function theorem in a non-Archimedean setting".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's get rid of the $R'$ and try the same thing this way.  f is differentiable at $X_0$ means that $\exists$  a g which is linear throughout some neighborhood U of $X_0$, g(X) = $f(X_0)$ + (M,$(X-X_0)$ [ where the second term is the inner product of $(X-X_0)$ with a constant vector M] and for which $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0}\frac{f(X) -g(X)}{X - X_0}$ = 0.  This means that f is practically linear throughout U.

Now if f were precisely linear we would have no problem, since $f(X) - f(X_0)$ = (M,$X-X_0)$ and this is uniformly continuous throughout U.  The problem is that f is not exactly linear.  I am using R(X) to represent the difference between f, the not quite linear, and g the exactly linear.

So the question of uniform continuity of f in the neighborhood U comes down to the behavior of R(X) in U. What do we know about R? We know that $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0} \frac{R(X)}{X-X_0}$ = 0 and further that the convergence is uniform **in U.**  That means that if you pick an $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta$ independent of X  such that in $V \subset U$ a neighborhood of $X_0$  of radius $\delta$, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are in V  then $\frac {|R(X_1) - R(X_2)|}{|X_1-X_2|}$ < $\epsilon$.    Substituting back the definition of R we have

$R(X_1)$ = $f(X_1)-g(X_1)$ = $f(X_1) - f(X_0)- (M,(X_1-X_0))$ and similarly for $X_2$. So

$\frac {|R(X_1) - R(X_2)|}{|X1-X_2|}$ = $\frac{f(X_1) -f(X_2) - [(M,(X_1-X_0))-(M,(X_2-X_0))]}{X_1 - X_2}$ < $\epsilon$ when $X_1, X_2$ are in V.

We get $|f(X_1)-f(X_2)|$ < $\epsilon|(X_1-X_2)|$ + $[(M,(X_1-X_0))-(M,(X_2-X_0))]$. The terms in square brackets go to 0 uniformly as $X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ because they are the difference of a linear function at 2 points in V, and the $\epsilon|(X_1-X_2)|$ likewise .

Answer (score 0):

The proof of theorem $3.4$ in your [reference](http://www.physics.umanitoba.ca/~khodr/Publications/RSImplicitFT-Final.pdf) contains the idea to solve the problem: **one has to prove the continuity of partial derivatives**.
The reasoning is valid apart from the *non-Archimedean* and *local* context of the writing.

In the $\varepsilon-\delta \,$ game let $\delta \,$ be a reply to $\varepsilon /4$ as for the *differentiability* of $\mathbf f$ and let $\delta_1$ be a reply to $\varepsilon \delta/4$ as for the *continuity* of $\mathbf f$.

In the following $f_j^i$ is the derivative of $f^i$ respect to $x_j \,$.

Now choose $\mathbf x,\mathbf y \in U$ such that $||\mathbf x-\mathbf y||<\min \{\delta,\delta_1\}$.
Then $$|f_j^i(\mathbf x)\delta-f_j^i(\mathbf y)\delta| \le$$$$|f^i(\mathbf x+\delta\hat {\mathbf e}_j)-f^i(\mathbf x)-f_j^i(\mathbf x)\delta|$$$$+ \,|f^i(\mathbf y+\delta\hat {\mathbf e}_j)-f^i(\mathbf y)-f_j^i(\mathbf y)\delta|$$$$+ \,|f^i(\mathbf x)-f^i(\mathbf y)|+|f^i(\mathbf x+\delta\hat {\mathbf e}_j)-f^i(\mathbf y+\delta\hat {\mathbf e}_j)|$$$$< \varepsilon \delta$$from which the continuity of $f_j^i \,$.
The continuity of the (total) derivative follows from $$||\mathbf f'(\mathbf x)-\mathbf f'(\mathbf y)|| \le \left \{\sum_{i,j} \;[f_j^i(\mathbf x)-f_j^i(\mathbf y)]^2 \right \} ^\frac 12 $$by the Schwarz inequality.

**Edit**:$\;$ OP advises that the proof doesn't work: in fact the uniform continuity of $\mathbf f$ is not assured because $U$ is open.

**new attempt**

Let $U$ be simply open: I want to prove that $f'$ is uniformly continuous on the set$$U_{\Delta}=\{x\in U:\ {\rm dist}\,(x,\Bbb R^m\backslash U)>\Delta\}$$with $\Delta>0$ chosen sufficiently small.

Avoiding some detail, let $x \in U_{\Delta}$ and let $\delta>0$ corresponding to $\varepsilon>0$ and such that $\delta<\Delta$.

We have $$(f'(x+h)-f'(x))(k)=$$$$-[f(x+k)-f(x+h)-f'(x+h)(k-h)]+$$$$f(x+k)-f(x)-f'(x)(k)+$$$$f(x)-f(x+h)-f'(x+h)(-h)$$$$$$Take $h$ and $k$ so that $\|h\|<\frac \delta 2$ and $\|k\|=\|h\|\,$: hence $x+h,x+k \in U$.

Then $$\|(f'(x+h)-f'(x))(k)\|<4\varepsilon \|k\|$$

Now let $u \in \mathbb R^m$ such that $\|u\|=1$ and let $k=\|h\|\,u\,$: we have $$\|(f'(x+h)-f'(x))(u)\|<4\varepsilon$$Then $$\|f'(x+h)-f'(x)\|\le4\varepsilon$$$$$$

Comment: [@TonyPiccolo] Then $\displaystyle \delta_1=\delta_1(\frac{\epsilon \delta}{4},x)$ as $f$ is continuous only, $\delta_2=\min \{\delta,\delta_1\}$ should not depend on the points $x,y.$

Comment: The point is that $\mathbf f$ is uniformly continuous because it is uniformly differentiable: modify slightly the statement and the proof of proposition $3.3$ in your reference and you have the result.

Comment: [@TonyPiccolo] Note that $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly differentiable but $f$ is non-uniformly continuous.

Comment: Sorry, but I had forgotten that $U$ is open.

Comment: However do you think that proving the uniform continuity of partial derivatives is possible ? For me it should be the most natural way to solve your question.

Comment: [@TonyPiccolo] I think it is possible if U is open and connected using Lemma 3.6 of article , note that http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450911/uniform-differentiability

Comment: [@TonyPiccolo] How you proof that $\|(f'(x+h)-f'(x))(k)\|<3\varepsilon \|k\|$ ?

Comment: I edit supposing $\|k\|=\|h\|\,$ instead.

Comment: .@TonyPiccolo Note that $x+k$ not necessarily belong to $U$, $x$ can be well glued to the border of $U$, if fixed $||h||$  then also fixed $||k||$ .

Comment: .@TonyPiccolo I think $U$ is an connected open, we need a counterexample.

Comment: Let $U$ be simply open: then $f'$ is u.c. on $\{x\in U:\ {\rm dist}\,(x,\Bbb R^m\backslash U)>\Delta\}$ with $\Delta>0$ chosen sufficiently small. I edit with $\delta$ chosen in $(0,\Delta)$.

Answer (score 0):

From the uniform differentiabilty, we can find a $t>0$ such that, for every ${\bf v}$ with $\|{\bf v}\| \le 2t$ and ${\bf x} \in U$, ${\bf x} + {\bf v} \in U$,

$$ t^{-1}\| f({\bf x}) - f({\bf x}+{\bf v}) + f'({\bf x}){\bf v}\| < \frac{\epsilon}{5}$$

Now, let take any ${\bf x}$, ${\bf y}$ such that $\|{\bf x} - {\bf y}\| < t$, and  ${\bf x}, {\bf y} \in U$. Define ${\bf k}$ = ${\bf y} - {\bf x}$.

Note that for any $t{\bf w}$ with $\| {\bf w} \|=1$, we have $\|t{\bf w} + {\bf k}\| < 2t$.

We then have, for every ${\bf x}$ such that an open ball of radius $2t$ is contained in $U$,

> $$\begin{align} \left\| f'({\bf x}) - f'({\bf y})\right\|  
> &=  t^{-1}\max_{\|{\bf w}\|=1}\left\| f'({\bf x}){t\bf w} - f'({\bf x} +{\bf k})t{\bf w}\right\| \\
> &\le t^{-1}\max_{|{\bf w}|=1} \left\| ( f({\bf x}+t{\bf w}) - f({\bf x}) + f({\bf x} + {\bf k}) - f({\bf x} + {\bf k} + t{\bf w})   \right\| + \frac{2}{5}\epsilon \\
> &\le 
>  t^{-1}\max_{|{\bf w}|=1}\left\| f'({\bf x})({t\bf w} + {\bf h} -t{\bf w} -{\bf h})\right\| + \epsilon\\
> &= \epsilon
> \end{align}$$

However, I do not know how to prove it for ${\bf x}$ less than $2t$ away from a point outside $U$.

Maybe some sort of extension theorem would help?

Otherwise, we can strengthen the definition of uniform differentiability to the following:

$\forall \epsilon>0\,,\exists \delta>0:|\!|h|\!|<\delta,\color{blue}{x \in U} \Longrightarrow |\!|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)(h)|\!|<\epsilon |\!|h|\!|\qquad  $

in which case it does work.

Answer (score -1):

Let us start with the simplest case f:$R^1 \rightarrow R^1$.  The discussion below will generalize nicely to more dimensions.

Then f is differentiable at $x_0$ iff $ \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} {\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}}$ exists and is finite.  We call that limit $f'(x_0)$ .  So if f is differentiable at $x_0$  then we may write

f(x) = $f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + R(x)$ where  $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} R(x)/(x-x_0)$ = 0.      (1)

If f is uniformly differentiable that means

$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} R(x)/(x-x_0)$ converges uniformly to zero.     (2)

From (1) we have $f'(x)$ = $f'(x_0)$ + R'(x).  [We know R is differentiable because it is the difference between f which is differentiable and a linear polynomial.]

So $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} (f'(x)-f'(x_0))$ = $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} R'(x)$  = $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} R(x)/(x-x_0)$ = 0.  And this convergence is uniform as per our hypothesis as stated in (2).

Moving on to the case where $f:R^n \rightarrow R^m$. For this part of the discussion capital letters will be used to represent vectors (in whatever dimension).

According to many sources (and I will state specifically Robert Sealey "Calculus of Several Variables") f is differentiable at $X_0$ iff there exists a linear function g (X) = $f(X_0)$ + $(M,X-X_0)$  [where M is a constant vector and (a,b) means the inner product], such that

$ \lim_{X \rightarrow X_0} {\frac{f(X)-g(X)}{|X-X_0|}}$ = 0.   (3)

If f is uniformly differentiable that means simply that this limit converges uniformly.We could have stated differentiability this way in the $R^1 \rightarrow R^1$ case, but I stated it as I did in that case to throw some light on what g actually is.

Let R(X) = f(X) - g(X) $\Rightarrow$  f(X) = g(X) + R(X). Since R = f - g then $R/|x-x_0| \rightarrow 0$ uniformly. Notice also that $R(X_0)$ = 0, since it is $f(X_0) - g(X_0)$ and by (3) this must be 0.  Since g is linear and f is differentiable R is also differentiable and from the above $R'(X_0)$ = 0.

Looking at $f'$ we have
$f'(X) = g'(X) + R'(X) = M + R'(X)$;
$f'(X_0) = M + R'(X_0)$ and thus $f'(X_0) = M$.

Finally $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0} (f'(X)-f'(X_0))$ = $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0} R'(X)$ = $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0}{\frac{R(X)-R(X_0)}{X-X_0}}$ = $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0}{\frac{R(X)}{X-X_0}}$  and this goes to 0 uniformly because f is uniformly differentiable, R = f - g, and $R(X_0)$ is 0.

Comment: Haven't you assumed $R'$ is continuous? Can we deduce continuously differentiable from uniformly differentiable?

Comment: @BettyMock Note that $f$ is uniformly differentiable if $\forall \epsilon>0\,,\exists \delta>0:|\!|h|\!|<\delta,\color{blue}{[x,x+h]\subset U} \Longrightarrow |\!|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)(h)|\!\!|<\epsilon |\!|h|\!|$

Comment: In fact I think that for your convergence to be uniform you have used that $R'$ is uniformly continuous when you replaced $\lim_{X \to X_0} R'(X)$ with $R'(X_0)$, so the argument seems circular.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis -- The R(x)/$(X-X_0) \rightarrow $ 0 is exactly equation (3), which is the definition of differentiable. f is uniformly differentiable is equivalent to (3) converges uniformly. Re $R'(X_0)$ = 0 we have $(R(X)-R(X_0))/|X-X_0|$ = $R(X)/|X-X_0|$; this converges to 0 uniformly because it is equation (3) where convergence is uniform.  And of course this limit is $R'(X_0)$. So I don't think I'm going in a circle.  I relied strictly on the definition of differentiable and the given uniform convergence.  I don't think I am assuming anywhere that R' is continuous.

Comment: @felipeuni.  That is a correct definition of uniformly differentiable.  However, every definition can be stated in different ways.  I am stating it as equation (3) converges uniformly.  If you check it out, you will see they are equivalent.

Comment: @BettyMock: From definitions we have $\lim_{X\to X_0} R'(X) = \lim_{X \to X_0} \lim_{Y \to X} (R(Y)-R(X))/(Y-X)$; my problem is how you collapsed this down to the single limit $R'(X_0)$, which seems to be assuming continuity of the derivative.

Comment: AnthonyCarapetis -- $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0}R'(X)$ = $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0} \frac{R(X)-R(X_0)}{|X-X0|}$ = $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0} \frac{R(X)}{|X-X0|}$ =$R'(X_0)$ by definition , since $R(X_0)$ = 0. We know that $R'(X_0)$ exists because R = f-g and both f and g are differentiable.  Also $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0} \frac{R(X)-R(X_0)}{|X-X0|}$ = $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0}  \frac {f(X) - g(X)}{|X-X_0|}$. (continued)

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis (continued).  The right hand side of this converges uniformly to 0 by the definition of "f is uniformly differentiable at $X_0$".  That is how I conclude $R'(X_0)$ = 0.  It is all from the basic definitions.  I do not anywhere claim that $R'$ is continuous at $X_0$. Your expression with Y - X is a general definition of $R'(X)$, which is exactly the same as mine with X - $X_0$. One needs to use it only once.

Comment: @BettyMock: You haven't addressed my concern, which is with your very first equality. $\lim_{X \rightarrow X_0} \frac{R(X)-R(X_0)}{|X-X0|} = R'(X_0)$ by definition, not $\lim_{X \to X_0} R'(X)$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis We do not know a priori that $\lim_{X-X_0}R'(X)$ goes to $R'(X_0)$ or goes to anything in particular, or even exists; and I do not anywhere claim it does.  That is quite irrelevant to what I am doing here.  I claimed that $R'(X_0)$ exists and is 0 because it is [by definition of derivative at $X_0$]  $\frac{R(X)-R(X_0)}{|X-X_0|}$ = $\frac{f(X) -g(X)}{|X-X_0|}$ [by definition of R] and this last term goes to 0 uniformly [by definition of "f is uniformly differentiable at $X_0$"].

Comment: @BettyMock: why do you keep leaving out the limit in the definition of $R'$? I agree that we have $R_{x_0}(x)/|x-x_0| \to 0$ uniformly as $x \to x_0$, but this just means $R'_{x_0}(x_0) = 0$ where the convergence of the limit in the definition of the derivative is uniform. I don't see how to jump from here to the required conclusion which is the uniform convergence $R'_{x_0}(x) \to 0$ as $x \to x_0$. You seem to have just reduced the problem to showing the family of functions $R'_{x_0}$ is (uniformly in $x_0$) continuous at $x_0$ but not actually shown this.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis R(x) is clearly defined.  I do not understand what you mean by $R_{x_0}$(x). It seems clear to me that either you don't understand what I am saying or I don't understand what you are saying.  If anyone else can clarify this that would be helpful.

Comment: @BettyMock: there definitely seems to be some gap of comprehension between us. By $R_{x_0}(x)$ I just mean what you are calling $R(x) = f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$; I find it helps with the reasoning for the notation to explicitly express all dependences.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I rewrote my answer to get rid of the $R'$ since it seems to be a problem, and I also tried to explain better.  R does not depend on $X_0$ in the neighborhood of $X_0$.  R = f - g throughout that neighborhood. It is all analagous to the 1 dimensional case, which is why I wrote that one out.